# Do not allow google or anyother means access to site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am setting up some sub-domains on my server and am using them for staging and UA. I do not want these sites to be indexed or even possibly viewed by anyone but myself and the developers. .htaccess works for PHP but doesn't seem to work for asp.net. I was looking at changing the webconfig to do this but I think a separate file would work better. Anyone have an idea of what to use or do in this case?

thanks for your help

Tried to use .htaccess because the server or VPS says it have PHP availability, but it does not work.

````
 <Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 #allow from 1.1.1.1
 allow from .*n0where\.net.*
```</Limit>
````

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to block all requests except for a specified set of IP addresses (or a subnet) by adding a section similar to the following in your web.config.

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
            <add ipAddress="192.168.1.25" />
         </ipSecurity>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

For details and reference, please see the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/

Answer (score 0):

You could use iis "IP and Domain Restrictions" feature.

Enable this feature using:

- In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn
  Windows Features on or off.
- Expand Internet Information Services, then World Wide Web Services,
  then Security.
- Select IP Security, and then click OK.
- Now open IIS manager.
- In the Connections pane, expand the server name, expand Sites, and
  then site, application or Web service for which you want to add IP
  and Domain Name Restrictions.
- From Feature view Select "IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature".
- In the IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature, click Edit Feature
  Settings... From the Actions pane. Select Domain Name Restriction and Click Ok.
  [image]
- Now Click the Add Allow Entry... and specify the particular IP address from which one connection to the website has to be allowed (or the IP range if it is required)
  [image]

  You could follow below article for more detail:
  [IP Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/)

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: This could work, however I do not have access to Control panel. I am on VPS and Plesk is all I have to work with.

Comment: Actually in Plesk under iis there is a way to deny and add allowed ip addresses. So I have done that for now. My dev team is going to make a login layer because we are dealing with dynamic IPs... Thanks for your help!